# WIN32: Yielding execution to another (given) thread

Tags: windows, multithreading, winapi

I am looking for a way to yield the remainder of the thread execution's scheduled time slice to a different thread. There is a [SwitchToThread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686352%28VS.85%29.aspx) function in WINAPI, but it doesn't let the caller specify the thread it wants to switch to. I browsed MSDN for quite some time and haven't found anything that would offer just that.

For an operating-system-internals layman like me, it seems that yielding thread should be able to specify which thread does it want to pass the execution to. Is it possible or is it just my imagination?

Comment: Even if you could do this, it would be a very bad idea. You would effectively be rewriting the OS scheduler inside your own application. No good can come of trying to do such at thing!

Comment: @All: agreed, doing this could lead to a situation where other threads (e.g.: system-critical ones) would starve, and is a bad idea in general.

@ChrisW, @dsolimano: I thought about fibers, but a thread can only schedule a fiber that runs in the scheduling thread's context. In this particular case I need to execute my code on a specific thread (DirectX requires that).

@Miky, @Nikolai: thanks for the suggestion of an alternative approach - that's what I was looking for.

Comment: I suggest you also read about "co-routines" for more platform-agnostic theory and ideas in this area, though I think you're probably best off sticking with Win32 concepts, and probably threads rather than fibers.

Comment: @Marcin, glad to be able to help. If you'd like to learn more about multi-threading in Windows I suggest you pick up a copy of Joe Duffy's Concurrent Programming on Windows (http://www.bluebytesoftware.com/books/winconc/winconc_book_resources.html) it's an excellent read for beginners and seasoned programmers alike.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason you can't yield processor time-slices to a designated thread is that Windows features a **preemptive scheduling kernel** which pretty much places the responsibility and authority of scheduling the processor time in the hands of the kernel and only the kernel.

As such threads don't have any control over when they run, if they run, and even less over which thread is switched to after their time slice is up.

However, there are a few way you may influence context switches:

- by increasing the priority of a certain thread you may *force* the scheduler to schedule it more often in the detriment of other threads (obviously the reverse applies as well - you can lower the priority of other threads)
- you can code your process to place threads in kernel wait mode when they don't have work to do in order to help the scheduler do it's job.  When using proper kernel wait constructs such as Critical Sections, Mutexes, Semaphores, and Timers you effectively tell the kernel a certain thread doesn't need to be scheduled until a certain codition is met.

*Note: There is rarely a reason you should tamper with task priorities so USE WITH CAUTION*

Answer (score 3):

You might use 'fibers' instead of 'threads': for example there's a Win32 API named [SwitchToFiber](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686350(VS.85).aspx) which lets you specify the fiber to be scheduled.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at UMS (User-mode scheduling) threads in Windows 7

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd627187(VS.85).aspx

Comment: Ah, it looks like a very interesting read. Unfortunately I'm targetting both 32 and 64 bit platforms from XP upwards and can't use it. What a shame. Thanks for pointing that to me, though!

Comment: UMS addresses the issue that was highlighted in Miky Dinescu's answer.

Answer (score 2):

The second thread can simply wait for the yielding thread either by calling WaitForSingleObject() on its handle or periodically polling GetExitCodeThread().  The other answers are correct about altering the operating system's scheduling mechanisms - it is better to design the threads properly in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. Only the kernel can decide what code runs next though you can influence it by reducing the non-waiting threads it has to choose from to run next, and by setting thread priorities with [SetThreadPriority](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686277(VS.85).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular synchronization primitives like events, semaphores, etc. to serialize your two threads. This does not in any form prevent the kernel from scheduling *other* threads in between, or in parallel on another CPU core, or *virtually simultaneously* on the same core. This is due to [preemtive multitasking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preemption_(computing)) nature of modern general purpose operating systems.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do your own scheduling under Windows, you can use [fibers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682661(VS.85).aspx), which essentially are threads that you have to schedule yourself.  However, given that you describe yourself as a layman to the OS internals world, that would probably be a bad idea, as fibers are something of an advanced feature.

Comment: Hey, it's not like I'd cause any serious harm - there's always a good opportunity to learn and be less of a layman. Learning new things is (almost) never a bad idea :)

Answer (score 0):

Can I ask *why* you want to use SwitchToThread?

If for example it's some form of because thread x is computing some value that you want to wait for on thread Y, then I'd really suggest looking at the Parallel Pattern Library or the Asynchronous Agents Library in Visual Studio 2010 which allows you to do this either with message blocks (receive on an asynchronous value) or simply via tasks : wait for a set of tasks to complete and inline their execution while waiting...

```
//i.e. on an arbitrary thread
task_group* tasks;
tasks->run(... / some functor/)
```

a call to tasks->wait() will wait and inline any tasks running.

Comment: As for the "why" part - I don't remember the exact scenario I had in mind when I posted my question originally, but in general, I'm looking for a way to ensure my application (a simple game engine I'm making) gets some of the scheduler's attention as often as possible - ideally in every time slice. I want to keep it as smooth as possible, and have a budget of 16.67ms of processing time per frame with 60Hz screen refresh rate. A simple test proved that my thread can get preempted for more than 10ms. I guess I'll just have to live with fact a frame may be skipped if I want to be nice for the OS.

Comment: As for the "PPL" and "AAL" - they look very interesting, thanks for showing them to me.

Comment: If you really want to take muck with priorities then take a look at AvSetMmThreadCharacteristics and AvSetMmThreadPriority. They are appropriate for what your scenario of providing guarantees.

Again I'd encourage you to look at the APIs. I'm also writing a game to demonstrate how this can be done with them.